# Programmatically clear Python Interpreter window in Pyscripter?

Tags: python, pyscripter

Is there an API for controlling the PyScripter Python Interpreter window? I'd like basic control such as clearing the screen.

I'm aware of (and using) the option to Clear output before run, but I'm specifically looking for an option to achieve this programmatically.

I've tried using system calls to CLS but this doesn't work in the Python Interpreter window. I've also tried using ANSI escape codes but it looks like this too is not supported in the Python Interpreter window.

Another solution I've considered is printing a lot of newlines but this solution doesn't truly clear the screen.

Edit: Using another IDE/console/environment is not an option for me at this point.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=49) which has been marked `Fixed`.

Comment: I also found something which said "Right-click on the interpreter window and select Clear All."

Comment: Unfortunately adding a keyboard shortcut or using the right click -> "Clear All" option won't work, I particularly need programmatic control.

Answer (score 0):

in shortcuts/interpreter/actClearContents = [shortcut-of-your-choice]
=> clear the console